# Play framework routes problems with query String

Tags: playframework

I have route

```
GET /public/img/sv_{oldid}.jpg?code={code}&id={id}

Application.fetchImage(code,id)
```

and method in Java class

```
public static void fetchImage(String code, Long id)
{
    System.out.println(id + "   i  " + code);
}
```

and when I try to put URL  website

```
127.0.0.1:900/public/img/sv_8.jpg?code=ABC&id=12
```

in console I get error :

> *Ignoring code,id (static params must be specified as key:'value',...)*

and if I change `?` to `/` in route it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write down the parameter's name in function. try this

```
GET     /public/img/sv_{<[0-9]+>old_id}.jpg   Application.fetchImage
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of play you are using. But this works out for me(play 2.2.2):

```
GET  /store/:store_id/book/new  controllers.Application.newMemory(store_id: String, bookname: String ?= "")
```

This router can match:

**/store/store01/book/new?bookname=somebook**, which will call *controllers.Application.newMemory("store01", "somebook")*

**/store/store02/book/new**, which will call *controllers.Application.newMemory("store02", "")*